# How to compute poker straight

Tags: probability, poker

I am trying to understand how we got 10,240 possible straights in the game of poker. Of the formula that have found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight it is coherent with I understand the demoninator - which indicates the possible hands that can be dealt - and part of the numerator - i.e. 10 represents the possible hands involving a straights independently from the suite. What I do NOT understand is the 4^5 factor, can someone please kindly explain it to me?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: given 5 ordered cards, how many ways can you assign 4 suits to them?

Answer (score 5):

To spell out deinst's comment, the top value card in the straight can come from any of the $4$ suits, the second top value card can come from any of the $4$ suits, the third from any of the $4$ suits, the fourth from any of the $4$ suits, and the fifth from any of the $4$ suits, giving $4\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4 = 4^5$ possibilities for the suit.

Meanwhile the top value can be any of Ace, King, ..., down to $5$, which gives $10$ possibilities, and $10 \times 4^5 = 10240$.