# What will be the count of "4cardstraight" in a Poker Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

Let's modify the  poker hand(fake):  "4cardstraight"  -- i.e. a straight, but with only 4 cards in a row instead of 5.

Rules of the game:

1. A hand is counted as a "4cardstraight" if it includes 4 cards in a row, but not 5 (so it's not a regular 5-card straight).
2. When a hand qualifies as multiple types, it should be counted as  the highest-value hand; for this purpose, the value of "4cardstraight" will be just below a straight.

In such game what will be count of "4cardstraight" ?

I found an answer for the regular poker game to count the straight at wikipedia page and explanation in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113403/79395).
So my approach is to count all the number of sequences(having a straight of 4 and 5) and then subtract 10*4^5  from the answer to get count of "4cardstraight".

But I am not able to figure out that how can I calculate the count for all straight of size >=4.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems straightforward to count directly. From your count of straights, it looks as if you are allowing Aces high or low.

Viewing by bottom card, there are $11$ types of $4$-card straight. But $2$ of the types are special, the Ace low and the Ace high. For each of these $2$ types, the cards that make up the straight can be chosen in $4^4$ ways, and the odd card in $44$ ways. (if we are building a $4$-card straight of type Ace, 2, 3, 4, we will not be using any alredy chosen card, and we must avoid 5's). This gives a total of $(2)(4^4)(44)$.

For each of the $9$ other types, the odd card can have any of $40$ values. For example, if we are building a $4$-card straight that goes 8, 9, 10, J, we must avoid the 7's and the Queens.  This gives a total of $(9)(4^4)(40)$.

Add up the two numbers obtained.

Comment: I am not sure with your solution.... having a 5 card card staright gives a combination of "10200" so for a 4 card it should it should be above this values. but adding the values you have provided gives a very large value. please help.

Comment: I counted $4$-card straights, **including** the straight flushes. Yes, there are a lot more of these than there are $5$-card straights, about $11$ times as many. If you don-t want to count the straight flushes, replace $4^4$ in both places by $4^4-4$, that is, $252$. Doesn't make a big percentage difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for 4cardstraight is 97476 as suggested here.
http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/mag12/